# lines in canvas appears as dots

Tags: javascript, canvas

im making a simple drawing app but whenever i try to draw something it doesnt appear right instead it just looks like bunch of dots however if i move my mouse slowly, it appears right.

here is my code:

````
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let draw = false;

let currentX, currentY;

let lineWidth = 15;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    draw = true;
})

document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    draw = false;
})

document.addEventListener('mousemove', startDrawing)



function startDrawing(e) {
    if(!draw) return

    currentX = e.clientX
    currentY = e.clientY

    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(currentX, currentY);
    ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
    ctx.stroke()
}```  
.
````

Comment: Please spend more time properly formatting your post.

Comment: Actually, per specs you should not even have dots rendered here, but only Safari follows the specs here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on every line's starting point. If you move up to P then draw a line up to P, the result is clearly a dot.

Instead, leverage the cached coordinate pair for the initial move, then draw the line up to where the cursor is. Finally, update the cache.

```
function startDrawing(e) {
    if(!draw) return

    //currentX = e.clientX
    //currentY = e.clientY

    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(currentX, currentY);
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    //ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
    ctx.stroke()

    currentX = e.clientX
    currentY = e.clientY
}
```

To make the things better, you should avoid to draw the first line from when the mouse is pressed. Try to draw something, then release, then draw again: you'll see that there's a line connecting the last point of the first session with the first of the last one.

To correct this, you can adjust as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    draw = true;
    currentX = currentY = undefined;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, you draw each time the `mousemove` event is triggered. The event is not triggered for each pixel you move.

You need to store the position of the last event and then connect the positions with lines.